# trying to code a button to search for an item (text) and replace a corresponding number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having some issues with this.

I have a spreadsheet which optimises levels of items based on heavy calculations. it displays a list of the top 5 artifacts to increase the level of, including the cost and final level. I want a button which when clicked copies the top results final level and replaces its actual level with this.

on one sheet i have a table (example)

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      artifact       |     cost         |      levels         |   final level    |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       art 1         |       1000       |       500           |      1500        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

on another sheet i have another table,

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|  current Level      |     Artifact     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        1000         |      Art1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        2500         |      Art2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         300         |      Art3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         400         |      Art4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

When clicking the button which will be located on the first sheet i want the code to search for the artifact, (in this case Art1) and either add the levels to the current level on sheet 2 or if easier replace the current level with the final level.

I have been playing around, very unsuccessfully. i have searched long and hard. i have managed this in excel using the indirect function to call upon a cell which has the resulting cell location (ie. B5) already calculated using match written in it. indirect doesnt seem to work in google scripts.

an example of my mess is below

```
    function Apply() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssopt = ss.getSheetByName("Artifact Optimiser");
var ssart = ss.getSheetByName("Artifacts");

var Artifacts = ssart.getRange('C2:C79').getValues();
var ArtifactsAfterAEC = ssopt.getRange('C10:F10').getValues();


//column with Levels B=2
//i<1 - 1 - num of max Artifacts in Summary
//j>78 - 78 - num of rows in Artifacts Section

for(var i=0; i<1; ++i) {
  for(var j=0; j<78; ++j) {
    if(Artifacts[j] == ArtifactsAfterAEC[i]) {
    ssart.getRange(j,2).setValue(ArtifactsAfterAEC[i][4]);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please Tag your question with the appropriate language. [About Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Hi. I'm looking at older questions, like yours, that don't have any comments or answers. Did you resolve your "problem", or are you still looking for help?